# How to marshal JSON with lowercase keys

Tags: json, go, amazon-dynamodb, marshalling

I use AWS Lambda with DynamoDB using golang.

My DynamoDB table use lowercase attribute names such as `id` or `name`.

In Go, if I want to be able to marshal a struct correctly, I have to name fields starting with a capital letter.

```
type Item struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
}
```

To put an item into my DynamoDB table, I have to marshal it into a `map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue`, using `dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap` function.

```
item := Item{
    ID: "xxxx",
    Name: "yyyy"
}

av, _ := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)
```

Of course, this will create a `map` using names written as `ID` and `Name`, which are incompatible with `id` and `name` from the dynamodb table.

Reading the documentation, I found that you can use a custom encoder, and enable json tags.

```
type Item struct {
    ID   string  `json="id"`
    Name string  `json="name"`
}

func setOpts(encoder *dynamodbattribute.Encoder) {
    // Not sure which one I sould set
    // So I set them both :)
    encoder.SupportJSONTags = true
    encoder.MarshalOptions.SupportJSONTags = true
}

func main() {
    encoder := dynamodbattribute.NewEncoder(setOpts)

    encoder.Encode(...)
}
```

But here the `encoder.Encode()` method is only used to create a `dynamodb.AttributeValue`, and not a `map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue`.

Is there a way to use a custom encoder with `MarshalMap`? Or am I using it in a wrong way?

**EDIT:**

Okay so as Zak pointed out, there is a `dynamodbav` tag that can be used.

I also found out that I was using `json` tags in a wrong way. I should use the syntax `json:"id"` instead of `json="id"`.

Indeed, DynamoDB SDK uses the json tag if available, and this one can be overrided by the `dynamodbav`.

So all I had to do was to make my structure looks like this and it worked

```
type Item struct {
    ID   string  `json:"id"`
    Name string  `json:"name"`
}
```

Comment: JSON tags should be of the form ``json:"id"`` not ``json="id"``, [per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

Comment: yep indeed, I saw that too, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dynamo's built in marshalling, from `MarshalMap(...)` can support struct tags, similar to json.

You can add them to the type that you are marshalling, like so:

```
type Item struct {
    ID   string `dynamodbav:"id"`
    Name string `dynamodbav:"name"`
}
```

[See the docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Marshal)

Comment: It was pretty easy indeed, I did a pretty bad job reading the documentation, thank you

Comment: I really thought the `json:"id"` tag is supported, but looking at [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue#MarshalWithOptions) it's vague. The original [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1569) did mention `json` expected to work, but in [PR](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/pull/1590) `json` is not mentioned. IMO `json` should be supported, but now package `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue` 1.10.0, `json` tag still not working lowercase not honored. Anyway you can still do `dynamodbav:"id" json:"id"`.